# How to set navigation bar back Arrow and backBarButtonItem title with different colors swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I trying to set my detailed view controller navigation bar with arrow image and backBarButtonItem title as like below

[image]

I have tried to add arrow image like below..

```
let imgBackArrow = UIImage(named: "backArrow")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = imgBackArrow
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = imgBackArrow
```

Then I am trying to set title with black color and with multiple lines(for larger text) but nothing is working for me any help..?

```
    let customButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: eventName, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: nil)
customButton.tintColor = UIColor.black; //giving me black image as well
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem  = customButton
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom class for navigation Bar. like customNavigationBar and an xib for UIView and in your xib take a button set its image and take a label and give constraints...
And take a UIView on your ViewController and place it at the top and give the class name customNavigationBar

customNavigationBar class

```
 import UIKit

 class customNavigationBar: UIView {

 //Mark:- Iboutlets
 @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!



 //Mark:- Lifecycle

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
 super.init(frame: frame)
 commonInit()
 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
 super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 commonInit()
 }


 }
 //Mark:- Function

 extension customNavigationBar{
 private func commonInit(){
 Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customNavigationBar", owner: self, options: nil)
 addSubview(containerView)
 containerView.frame = self.bounds
 containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight , .flexibleWidth]
 }
 }
```

And your xib file's owner name must be customNavigationBar

Now in your ViewController  class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: customNavigationBar!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            navigationBar.titleLabel.text = "Texas Rangers at"
            navigationBar.titleLabel.textColor = .blue
            navigationBar.backButton.addTarget(self, action : #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        }

        @objc func backButtonTapped() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Now this customNavigationBar view you can use any viewController no need to set every time navigationBar in every viewController

Comment: plz note....     backButton
 titleLabel
 containerView  this are the outlets from your xib to customNavigationBar class